# How can I get serviceCredentials > windowsAuthentication > allowAnonymousLogons to work in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-authentication

I have a WCF service exposed as a netTcpBinding.

On the service side:

```
<netTcpBinding>             
    <binding> 
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>         
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding> ...
// Service behavior
<behavior>         
    <serviceCredentials>
       <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true" />
     </serviceCredentials>          
</behavior>
```

I am unable to access this service from a anonymous user on another machine. (Error: Negotiation failed redentials could not be verified.)

What does

```
<windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true" />
```

do?

I want my service to be accessible to both windows and anonymous users over net tcp binding. I can do this using UserName validation, but how do I do this using Windows authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the AllowedImpersonationLevel on the client?

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <clientCredentials>
          <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Anonymous"/>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

or

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Anonymous;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article [Debugging Windows Authentication Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb463274%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) points out the need to combine your service configuration with the client configuration mentioned by @user1467261. It points to another article on impersonation in WCF for more detail - but glossing over it, the need to combine these settings is not entirely obvious.